# failed to create the configuration database system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, installation, configuration-wizard

I am attempting a single server installation of SharePoint 2007 SP2 on Windows Server R2 with SQL Server 2005 SP3. The SharePoint binaries installed correctly but when I try to create the config databases I get the following error message:

> Failed to create the configuration database.
>   An exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown.  Additional exception information: CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 3(error not found) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'E:\SQL Logs\SharePoint_Config_log.LDF'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 3(error not found) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'E:\SQL Logs\SharePoint_Config_log.LDF'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.EnsureSqlDatabase(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.SetDatabaseOptions(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString, Dictionary`2 options, Boolean wYukon)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Provision(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString, SqlFile sqlFileId, String sqlSignaturePath, Dictionary`2 options)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Provision(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

I have attempted to create the databased both via the Configuration Wizard and with the PSCONFIG command line tool.

The setup account has dbowner and securityadmin permissions on SQLServer and Full Control permissions to the all the drives.

What am I missing her guys?

Comment: Does the path 'E:\SQL Logs\' exist and does the SQL Server service account have NTFS Full Control rights on it?

Comment: Well I feel stupid! 
Thanks for that. I'd forgotten to create the root directory for the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the path E:\SQL Logs\ exists with the SQL Service account having NTFS Full Control over the folder.